# SQL Server while loop union all

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute this code below. It is a simplified example of the actual code I have to make, so I know that it is useless to loop in such a way.  However, I need to look and union select statements in SQL Server.  When I try to run this query I get an error:

> *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.*

Any ideas?

```
  DECLARE @position INT
    SET @position = -1

    WHILE(@position < 1)
    BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM mytable

    UNION ALL
    END
 SELECT * FROM mytable
```

Comment: Explain what you want to accomplish, not how. I guess you need a recursive query but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a second set to UNION on.  The while loop doesn't hold on to the selected set and know it the next time through.  What you're trying to accomplish is basically select all the data from mytable then union it again on the same set...n times.  Which really doesn't make sense. Remember that SQL is set based, so select * From mytable will select every record in there.  You also never state what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of trying to use `UNION` I would use a temp table or temp table variable to merge the result sets

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
  <COLUMNS>
)

 DECLARE @position INT
 SET @position = -1

 WHILE(@position < 1)
 BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #Temp (<COLUMNS>)
    SELECT * FROM mytable

    SET @position = @position + 1

 END

 SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

Answer (score 5):

That query makes no sense.  To use `UNION`, you need to be selecting from a second table.

SQL Server essentially sees:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable      

UNION ALL
```

With no second table after the `UNION`.

Comment: I want it to union with itself again.  There is no way to leave the union open and select the table again

Comment: So do `SELECT * FROM mytable UNION ALL SELECT * FROM mytable`?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I need to do that 50 times, and I just want to clean up the query.  All the where clauses are based of position

Comment: You want to `UNION ALL` to your table 50 times?

Comment: yes.  like I said the query is not simply select * from mytable.  There is a lot more

Comment: @rsoni - You're better off explaining something approximating your real need then to avoid getting a load of answers that will be of no use to you.

Answer (score 1):

This way gets rid of the the UNION statement and avoids a loop altogether:

```
DECLARE @position INT
SET @position = 5

DECLARE @n TABLE (n int)

INSERT INTO @n 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS x
FROM syscolumns

SELECT t.* 
FROM dbo.Table t
    CROSS JOIN @n n 
WHERE n <= @position
```