# Redirect outputs from Procedure with changing parameter values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Table had information about Employee Id's and their joining years. Ex: years vary from 2000-2015

I am trying to redirect output from the below query into a single table. Whereas right now I see output for 10 years in different tables. Any ideas on how i can redirect all years data into a single table?

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2000

WHILE @Year <= 2010
BEGIN
SELECT ID,JoiningYear from Table JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT ID
                               FROM     Table
                               WHERE    dept = 1
                                        AND joiningyear = @year
                             ) Q ON Q.id = Table.ssid
                                       AND joiningyear >= @year where JoiningYear=@year 

    SET @Year = @Year + 1
END
```

In a nut shell, how can I pass a parameter that can loop through the query for a condition and pop out all the data at once?

Comment: I think we need to understand the bigger problem - because if you want all the data at once, you can just `SELECT ID,JoiningYear from Table where JoiningYear=@year`and skip the whole loop/transaction.

Comment: Do you have an example of what the current table looks like and what the output should look like?

Comment: Added more specific logic needed. I need to get cohorts separately for specific conditions. and i need to pass the variable in all the conditions.

Comment: @Hines output looks like     Year ID 2000 45 2000 46 - In one table 2001 44 2001 47 in anotehr table.. I want them all in a single table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864558/sql-server-while-loop-union-all  This solution worked

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be as simple as ....

```
SELECT T.ID,  Q.JoiningYear 
from Table T
INNER JOIN Table Q ON Q.id = T.ssid
WHERE Q.dept = 1
 AND  Q.joiningyear >= 2000
 AND  Q.joiningyear <= @year
```